# Integrate flutter package in existing Android/iOS app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, adapter

I am trying to incrementally migrate two existing mobile apps (Android and iOS) to Flutter. The incremental migration is required because these apps have a huge codebase.

Since the two apps have the same business requirements (they need to do the same things) I want to start unifying the business logic (and maybe the repository logic) to flutter first (not the UI).

I have seen that it is possible to create a **flutter plugin**, which let you create an API in flutter, implemented with native code in Android and iOS. The communication between flutter and native code is permitted using "platform channels" (https://flutter.io/platform-channels/).

My question is: It is possible to use the same thing in reverse? Writing the API in Android/iOS code, integrate flutter as a gradle module/CocoaPods pod and use "platform channels" for communication?